# Get data from Esri ArcGIS MapServer API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to get a list of the recent earthquakes, with latitude and longitude from this API: https://apps.pdc.org/msf/rest/services/global/pdc_active_hazards/MapServer/6

I can't rely on a server-side library as I have to use only JavaScript in an HTML page.

My problem is that I can't find the list of the events browsing the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [documentation page](https://apps.pdc.org/msf/sdk/rest/index.html#/Query_Map_Service_Layer/02ss0000000r000000/) you're probably looking for, and as an example:

- to get all the data you'll want to set `WHERE` parameter to `1=1`
- to get all the data attribute columns set `outFields` to `*`
- to set the geometry spatial reference to lat/lng, you'll want `outSR` set to `4326`
- if you'd like JSON set the `format` to `pjson` or `json`

So all of the above parameters, in one request, would look like:

```
https://apps.pdc.org/msf/rest/services/global/pdc_active_hazards/MapServer/6/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=pjson
```

.. and should give you all the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was going crazy through the whole Esri documentation!